# Make Expandable Top Bar using JavaScript JQUERY or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It is possible to make Fixed Tob Bar or Bootom Bar menu, Drop Down menu using CSS and JQUERY. Is it possible to create a Expandable Top Bar just like in Android Phone.
Expandable means if I drag the Top Bar menu down, then it should expand its area upto the bottom of the page.

Comment: possible? yes. what have you tried?

Comment: did you mean Top Menu Bar should also come down with the page scrolling down?

Comment: not exactly like this but as seen in android phone i would like my page to see a top bar expandable.

Comment: @Joseph yeah but how? plz suggest any tutorial if you know!

Comment: Go to jQuery mobile, and use firebug to see how the header and footer display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible to replicate the Android notification bar effect, you just have to try. You could do a similar effect on hover, actually. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3shEE/

html:

```
<div id="expandable">
    <span>Hover over me</span>

    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
        <li>List 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

css:

```
#expandable {
    width: 100%; height: 50px;
    background: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#expandable span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px; text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expandable ul {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
}
​
```

javascript:

```
$("#expandable").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":"300px"},1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":"50px"},1000);
});​
```